# Prove two norms are equal if and only if each norm is less than or equal to 1.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vector space and let $||·||^*$ and $||·||^{**}$ be two norms on $X$. Prove that
$||x||^{*} = ||x||^{**} $ for all $x ∈ X$ if and only if

> $$\left \{x ∈ X : ||x||^* ≤ 1\right \} = \left \{x ∈ X : ||x||^{**} ≤ 1\right \}.$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

> Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and let $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$, $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ be two norms defined on $X$. Then $$\Vert x \Vert _1 = \Vert x \Vert_2 \tag{$\forall x \in X$}$$ if and only if $$\left\{x \in X : \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq 1\right\} = \left\{x \in X : \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq 1\right \}$$

---

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let's suppose that $\Vert x \Vert_1 = \Vert x \Vert_2$ for all $x \in X$. Then note that

$$\tag{1}x \in \left\{x \in X : \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq 1\right\} \implies \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq 1 \implies \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq 2 \implies x \in \left\{x \in X : \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq 1\right \}$$

and also that

$$\tag{2}x \in \left\{x \in X : \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq 1\right\} \implies \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq 1 \implies \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq 2 \implies x \in \left\{x \in X : \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq 1\right \}$$

With both $(1)$ and $(2)$ we conclude the first part of demonstration.

---

$(\Leftarrow)$ Now, consider true that $\left\{x \in X : \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq 1\right\} = \left\{x \in X : \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq 1\right \}$. Then we have that $\Vert x \Vert_1 \leq 1$ for all $x \in X$. But $X$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space than, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that  $\lambda x \in X $ so we have that

$$\Vert \lambda x \Vert_1 = \vert \lambda \vert \Vert x \Vert_1 \leq 1$$

If $x =0 $ then we have by definition of a norm that $\Vert x \Vert_1 = 0$ and $ \Vert x \Vert_2 =0$ which implies that $  \Vert x \Vert_1 = \Vert x \Vert_2$ if $x=0$. Take then $x \neq 0$. Define $\lambda:= 1/\Vert x \Vert_2$ and conclude $$\Vert x \Vert_1 \leq \Vert x \Vert _2\tag{3}$$

For the same reason we get that, for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ it is true that

$$\vert \alpha \vert \Vert x \Vert_2 \leq 1$$. So if $x \neq 0$ just take $\alpha := 1/\Vert x \Vert_1$. Conclude that

$$\Vert x \Vert _2 \leq \Vert x \Vert _1 \tag{4}$$

Then with $(4)$ and $(3)$ we conclude our proof.

Comment: Why do you say that if x=0, then ||x||*=||x||**? Would that not hold for x=1 instead?

Comment: If $x = 0$ then, by the definition of the norm, $\Vert x \Vert = 0$, for all norms, and we get the equality. I need to pic $x \neq 0$ to use $1/\Vert x \Vert$.

Comment: Sorry, where are you substituting x=0 into? I'm putting x=0 into ‖λx‖*=|λ|‖x‖**, which shows that 0=0?

Comment: $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is a norm then for $x \in X$,  $\Vert x \Vert = 0 \iff x=0 $

Comment: I just set above the equation 3 the $x=0$ to show that in this case we get our equality. Then I prove that the equality holds for all other $x \neq 0 \in X$. Then it holds for all $x \in X$

Comment: The property of a norm is, for $\lambda$ in the field we get $\Vert \lambda x \Vert = \vert \lambda \vert \Vert x \Vert$ for a general norm.  How did you go from one norm to the other?

Comment: Oh I think I see, are you using x=0 into ‖x‖1≤‖x‖2 where both sides evaluate to zero, so you say they are equal?

Comment: I just say that one norm is equal to zero and the other norm is also equal to zero.  I just use inequality for all the non-zero elements that remains to be prove the equality. This is a very general thing. Take any two norms given. Then we will always have that $\Vert 0 \Vert_1 = \Vert 0 \Vert_2$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the "only if", suppose $x\in X$. Choose a positive $\lambda$ in the field corresponding to the vector space $X$ such that $\lambda ||x||^* \leq 1$. Since $\lambda ||x||^*=||\lambda x||^*$ we now have $||\lambda x||^* \leq1$. Then $||\lambda x||^*=||\lambda x||^{**}$. Canceling the $\lambda$ on both sides gives that both norms are equal.